# Efficient way to convert HTML entites in mysql db to UTF-8 via php or command line

Tags: php, mysql, command-line, utf-8

I'm getting ready to migrate from an old Latin-1 database to UTF-8. I've already dumped the database and done the conversion on a copy.

Since I'm now using UTF-8, I thought it was high time to convert any HTML entities in the DB into their accented alternatives so that I'll have Stellan Skarsgård stored instead of Stellan Skarsg&aring;rd

I'm imagining the best way to do this would be to do a mysqldump followed by a search and replace that would convert all entities to their characters. That would streamline the process because I'd just be working on one dump file as opposed to writing a script that would have to be told which tables and columns to convert.

Is there a way to convert a mysqldump file this way via the command line? I can think of the process, just don;t know what tools to use.

Comment: If it's just a one-time operation I'd assume speed isn't so terrifically important, so a script which gets the data from the database, decodes the entities and updates the rows should be the safest thing to do. Using `information_schema` you can loop through all columns in all tables doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. Is there an example of how to use information_schema this way? I've never done it before.

Comment: Try ``SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'``. If you know the affected columns in the affected tables and it's not too many you can of course just do them directly.

Comment: Thinking through the logic here. I use that to get tables, then select table_name.column_name to get the data, loop through that and do the conversion. I'm stuck at how to do the UPDATE syntax if the where clause for each table can change. Might be missing something obvious here.

Comment: True, if your primary key is something different every time, that's going to be tough. If the tables have a consistent structure with, say, `id` as the primary key every time, it should be pretty easy... `SELECT id, $column FROM $table`, `UPDATE $table SET $column = $decodedValue WHERE id = $id`. If "`id`" is different every time or maybe not present at all, that's difficult. Maybe looking for an HTML entity decoder implementation for MySQL would be a good idea then, you can probably fire off a numbers of queries by hand once then.

Comment: I'll head off and look for one. Thanks for your advice.